# How to get test reports from inside a pod onto Gitlab console as artifact using Gitlab CI-CD?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm, gitlab-ci-runner, test-reporting

I'm using Gitlab CI-CD for my gradle project. I've attached an existing K8s cluster to Gitlab. Now, for the deployment, I am using helm. The executor is created on another K8s cluster. The deployment works fine. After the deployment I'm running certain BDDs (using gradle clean build as command inside the deployment.yaml)which creates a cucumber report in HTML format. Is there a way by which I can get that report as Gitlab artifact?

Comment: Rather then trying to run your tests inside a deployment, consider running them on a worker inside the same k8s cluster as your deployment. Then you can use the usual way to download build artifacts from gitlab:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my case the tests should be run from inside the same pod created as part of the deployment. I was thinking of using volumes, haven't given it a try yet.